# ctypes.ArgumentError: Don't know how to convert parameter

Tags: python, c, ctypes, python-c-extension

I define a function in C library as follows:

```
int* Test(char *str1,int id1,char *str2,float val,float *ls)
```

I want to use it in python so I write the following python code:

```
str1 = 'a'
str2 = 'b'
id1 = 0
val = 1.0
system('g++ -c -fPIC libtraj.cpp -o test.o')
system('g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,test.so -o test.so test.o')
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.so')
num_item = 100000
ls = (ctypes.c_float * num_item)()
lib.Test.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_int, shape=(num_item,))
lib.Test.argtypes = [c_char_p]
a = create_string_buffer(str1)
b = create_string_buffer(str2)
ls_id = lib.Test(a,id1,b,val,ctypes.byref(ls))
```

Then I run this python program. I met with error saying:

```
ls_id = lib.Test(a,id1,b,val,ctypes.byref(ls))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 4: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 4
```

What's wrong with my code?
Thank you all for helping me!!!

Comment: Try: `lib.Test.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_int, c_char_p, c_float, POINTER(c_float)]` (all defined by `ctypes`).

Comment: Also `ndpointer` seems to be related to _numpy_....if so, there's a great chance that mixing it with _ctypes_ won't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution provided by @CristiFati solves my problem. I just copy his answer in the comments and present here. Thank you @CristiFati.

Try:

`lib.Test.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_int, c_char_p, c_float, POINTER(c_float)] # (all defined by ctypes)`